# Finding the last repetition index of element in array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

How do you **retrieve the last repetition** index of element in array in C#?

For example you have: `int[] array = { 3, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4, 3 , 9 };`

And you are searching for 
element
3 where index of last repetition is 6.

This is what i have for finding first repetition:

```
public static int Search(int[] array, int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (value == array[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

PS: I can't use any functions or methods. I'm allowed to use only arrays.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Don't expect from SO to solve your homeworks...

Comment: I know to find the first repetition index of element, but don't know how to find the last.

Comment: If you have a solution for the first, then you have one for last, if you reverse the array....

Comment: What is j=i for in the above???

Comment: No functions? Clue you don't have to count up in a loop, you can also count down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to search from behind. If you search from the first element of the array, you'll definitely need to search until the end of the array. If you search from behind, you can return the value directly once you find it.

```
public static int search(int lem, int[] a)
{
    for (int i = a.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        if (lem == a[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
     return -1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague one. If you're looking for any *duplicate* (not necessary `3`) I suggest using `HashSet<int>` (C# implementation):

```
int[] array = { 3, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4, 3, 9 };

HashSet<int> used = new HashSet<int>();

int last = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
  if (!used.Add(array[i])) // failed to add to the set, array[i] is a duplicate
    last = i;

Console.Write(last);
```

In case you're looking just for the *last* ocurrence of `3`, try looping *backward*:

```
   int last = -1;

   for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
     if (array[i] == 3) {
       last = i;

       break;
     }
```

Comment: Is this possible to do whitout any functions, because i can use only arrays.

Comment: I'm unable to use LINQ and any other functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to find first repetition, why don't you use `array.Reverse()`, use the known algorythm, and then subtract found value form `array.Length`?

But if you want just a single method call, you can modify your solution, to not return the value until it finishes looping through an array:

```
public static int search(int lem, int[] a)
{
    int j = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) 
    {
        if (lem == a[i])
        {
            j = i;
        }
    }
    return j; 
}
```

Comment: I can't use any functions.

Comment: @Slasher I modified the solution to not use the functions